# SQL Concat Id column with another column

Tags: sql, sql-update, concatenation

Here is what I want to do:
I have this table

```
+----+-------------+  
| id | data        |  
+----+-------------+  
|  1 | max         |  
|  2 | linda       |  
|  3 | sam         |  
|  4 | henry       |  
+----+-------------+
```

and I want to Update the data with concatenating Id column with data, which will look like this:

```
+----+-------------+  
| id | data        |  
+----+-------------+  
|  1 | max1        |  
|  2 | linda2      |  
|  3 | sam3        |  
|  4 | henry4      |  
+----+-------------+
```

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Why would you want to do that, given that you could concatenate during a SELECT and leave the data as it is? And what have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: What are trying to achieve? Just to make `data` values unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this is basically what you want (T-SQL, Other platforms may have different methods for type conversion and concatenation):

```
update myTable
set data=data+convert(varchar(50),id)
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: Added platform.